# precision and speed inefficiency issues of Nearest function with sqrt expression

Tags: performance-tuning, nearest

Recently, `Nearest` has been attacked for many bugs. Some are already fixed.

I am going to show some issues when `Nearest` applied to data contains exact sqrt. Verified in version 10.3

**First issue: precision warning**

consider

```
data={{1/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2], 1 + 1/Sqrt[2], 5 Sqrt[2]}, {2 Sqrt[2], 2, 
  0}, {2 Sqrt[2], 2, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2], 2 + 1/Sqrt[2], 
  0}, {1/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2], 2 + 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {2 Sqrt[2], 2, Sqrt[
  2]}, {1/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2], 3 + 1/Sqrt[2], 
  0}, {1/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2], 3 + 1/Sqrt[2], 0}}
```

Now run this

```
test = data;
nnff = Nearest[test];
nnff[#] & /@ test; // AbsoluteTiming
```

you will get warnings like

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached
>   while evaluating (-2-1/Sqrt[2]+1/2 (4+Sqrt[2]))^2. >>

This is due to internal `N` operation. And sometimes, I also got this

> NearestFunction::mepcmp: -- Message text not found -- >>
>
> NearestFunction::mepcmp: -- Message text not found -- >>
>
> NearestFunction::mepcmp: -- Message text not found -- >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of NearestFunction::mepcmp will be
>   suppressed during this calculation. >>

Also "mepcmp" issue.

**Second: speed inefficiency with sqrt**

First, we generate data with random sqrt expression

```
data = Table[{RandomChoice[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}], 
    1/RandomChoice[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}]}, 1000];
```

then, we try default

```
In[1442]:= test = data;
nnff = Nearest[test];
nnff[#] & /@ test; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[1444]= {2.36139, Null}
```

Now we `N` data

```
In[1473]:= test = N@data;
nnff = Nearest[test];
nnff[#] & /@ test; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[1475]= {0.0480135, Null}
```

50 times faster now. But we got inexact version of original data.

But this can be solved simply with indexing the numerical values by exact values.

```
In[1482]:= test = Thread[N@# -> #] &@data;
nnff = Nearest[test];
nnff[#] & /@ test[[;; , 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[1484]= {0.0699132, Null}
```

the timing is comparable, and 40 times faster than the default setting but with the same result.

Also to notice, if we use this trick, we also get rid of the precision warning issue.

So I think mma should make this the default for sqrt expression.

PS:
Don't use `DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)`, it is extremely slow for sqrt (70 sec for the above example)
`DistanceFunction -> (Norm[N@#1 - N@#2] &)` is a lot better, but still 6 times slower than default (12 sec for the above example)

Comment: What if you use `DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance`?

Comment: @J.M. well, 54 sec. I update my post with timing

Comment: (1) Yes, it is much faster with machine numbers than exact. But it is up to you whether to coerce your data to machine precision, `Nearest` doesn't do it automatically, and note it may lead to different results. (2) As documented, `$MaxExtraPrecision` is used implicitly in various exact numerical computations, including equality tests, comparisons, and functions such as `Round` and `Sign`. (3) The lack of text for the `mepcmp` message is a bug.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ilian Thanks for pointing this out. I just found that the examples `data = 10^20 + RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {321, 4}];test = 10^20 + RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {23, 4}];` in the documentation page in the "working precision" par is not reproducable no matter how high workingprecision I set. na is still not equal to np

Comment: @matheorem This does seem like a bug and I have filed a report with the developers. Thank you for bringing it up. I believe `Nearest[data -> Automatic, test, Method -> "Scan"]` can be used as a workaround.

Comment: @ilian If so, then `Nearest` suffers too many bugs recently :(

Comment: Above bug has been fixed as of version 10.3.1.

Comment: @ilian Thank you for the information. I currently don't have 10.3.1. If you are sure, you can edit my post : )

Comment: @matheorem Just to clarify, by fixed I meant the documentation example with `WorkingPrecision`. The behavior in the question is not changing.

Comment: @ilian Ok, I see

Answer (score 7):

Before going into the issues you mention I'd like to point out the following in your code:

- An expression of the form: `nnff[#] & /@ test` can be simplified to `nnff /@ test` here.
- The `NearestFunction` generated by `Nearest` is effectively `Listable`, as shown in its [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction.html): "`Nearest[...][{x1, x2, ...}]` gives a list of the elements closest to each of the $x_i$". So you don't need to map `nnff`, you can just apply it: `nnff[#] & /@ test` is fully equivalent to `nnff[test]`.

---

Using your definition of random `data`...

```
data = Table[{RandomChoice[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}], 1/RandomChoice[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}]}, 1000];
```

... you can avoid the `$MaxExtraPrecision` error by specifying an explicit `WorkingPrecision` (e.g. machine precision) to use in the numerical comparisons:

```
num = Nearest[test, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision][test]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {0.00012, Null} *)
```

Notice that the above is quite fast and already returns fully symbolic results. This is equivalent to doing the numerical conversion explicitly with `N`:

```
symb = Nearest[N@test -> test][test]; // RepeatedTiming
num == symb

(* Out: 
{0.0001, Null}
True 
*)
```

Comment: +1.  Note `symb = Nearest[N@test -> Automatic][test]; // RepeatedTiming` with `num == (test[[#]] & /@ symb)` should be a little faster than `Nearest[N@test -> test]`.

Comment: Many thanks for letting me know `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` option, very useful ! BTW, the timing of `nnff[#] & /@ test` and `nnff /@ test` is almost the same

Comment: @matheorem, they have almost the same timing, but the former one looks clumsier, don't you think?